# Improved intersection of specific sorted sequences

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stl

I need perform intersection of 2 ordered sequences `[begin1, end1)`, `[begin2, end2)`. Obvious decision to use [std::set_intersection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) not looks an good idea after review section *Possible implementation*
The matter I don't like this one is in my sequences that is rather big (up to 1e6 items) and I have no clue which one. Following line of code:

```
while (first1 != last1 && first2 != last2) { ...
```

means that intersection may run over entire sequence.
So my question:

Is there in STL optimized version that may leverage idea of `std::lower_bound` that can reduce full scan to the `M+O(ln N)`

Comment: Do you think you can get lower than `N log N`? You still have to perform a linear scan of _one_ of the inputs, or you don't know what you're searching for in the other. If they're very different sizes, iterating over the shorter might help, I guess.

Comment: Couldn't you first dispatch on `.size()` of both sequences, then pass `.front()` of the smaller one to `std::lower_bound` to get a start iterator into the bigger sequence, and then use `.begin()`/`end()` of the smaller together with this start iterator and `.end()` of the larger sequence with `std::set_intersection`?

Comment: *Possible* implementation

Comment: Result size might be `Min(N,M)`, so you cannot hope to form it i logarithmic time. Linear time is possible with `merge` approach (*possible implementation* exploits it)

Comment: @Useless that is actually my point, I think that there must exists algorithm with `N Log N` complexity, while cppreference.com insist: "At most 2·(N1+N2-1)"

Comment: @lubgr, there are 2 aspects: (1) unfortunately I have only forward iterators specfication for sure, (2) Of course I can create my own join algorithm, but I wonder if STL may provide some optimization that tries to reduce full scan

Comment: If you've only got forward iterators, then you're going to (potentially) have to traverse the entire sequence. `lower_bound` won't really help you here.

Comment: @MarshallClow - you place super-comment (+1), so I extended my research and tried to reach improvement at least on std::set. Here is my observation: lower_bound gives a benefit over worst case (when outer loop runs over 1e6 items) but still worst when outer loop runs over smaller sequence